# error LNK2005: void __cdecl mongo::uasserted(...) already defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mongodb, visual-studio-2012

I get the error

`mongoclient.lib(assert_util.obj) : error LNK2005: void __cdecl mongo::uasserted(...) already defined in someOwnFile.obj`

at linking, along with `mongo::msgasserted` and `mongo::msgasserted`.

In `someOwnFile.cpp`, I have

```
#include <string>

#ifdef WIN32
// Needed for mongo BSON.
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4800)
#pragma warning(disable: 4244)
#pragma warning(disable: 4267)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#endif

#include <mongo/bson/bson.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif

// ...
```

Why do I get the error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it has problems when including just this file.

Now I'm doing this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
// Mongo uses boost.filesystem. Include it here to force to link it in (via its pragma lib).
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

// Needed for mongo BSON.
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4800)
#pragma warning(disable: 4244)
#pragma warning(disable: 4267)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#endif

#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>
#include <mongo/client/dbclient_rs.h>
#include <mongo/client/gridfs.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

And this works.